# Dynamically Change HTML DOM event

Tags: javascript, dynamic, bind

I am trying to dynamically change an element's onClick event and I have something like the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    getElementById('element' + i).onclick = function() { existingFunction(i); return false; };
}
```

Everything seems to work fine apart from the fact that the argument passed to 'existingFunction()' is the final value of i=4 each time it is called. Is there a way to bind a function to onclick that uses the value of i at the time of binding as opposed to what it seems to be doing at the moment and referencing the original i in the for-loop.

Also is is there a way of performing the same bind without having to create anonymous functions each time? so that I can directly reference 'existingFunction' in each onclick for performance reasons?

Cheers guys,
Yong

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734749/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582634/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933343/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579978/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413916/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    getElementById('element' + i).onclick = function() { existingFunction(i); return false; };
}
```

to

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    getElementById('element' + i).onclick = createOneHandler(i);
}

function createOneHandler(number){  
    return function() {  
        existingFunction(number); 
    }  
}
```

and it should work fine.

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/onovu3)**

A good explanation is given here

[JavaScript, time to grok closures](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/23/javascript-time-to-grok-closures.aspx)

Comment: Haha, the page you referenced is almost same situation. I read through the article and it was also very helpful thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

the code you posted should work the way you intended, your problem with i=4 is elsewhere. edit: this is wrong, rageZ is right about the scoping problem.

re the other question: all you can do is offload the verbosity with

```
var f = function (i) { return function () { existingFunction(i); return false; } }
for (...) { document.getElementById(...).onclick = f(i); }
```

BTW, you should use something like jQuery for DOM manipulation (concise syntax), and perhaps Zeta (http://codex.sigpipe.cz/zeta/) for the function composition

```
var f = compose(false_, existingFunction);
for (...) { $(...).click(f(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

for the `i` being always 4, you have a scoping problem, I advise to read [this](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/). Scoping is are **really important** concept, so you have better to make sure to understand what's is going on.

a better code would be

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    getElementById('element' + i).onclick = existingFunction;
}
```

the onclick would pass an event has argument so you can know what element have been clicked
i.e.

```
function existingFunction(event){
  // DO something here
}
```

you can read more about events [there](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html). IE does have the exact same event model as other browser so you would have to handle it.

Last bit, I advise you to use a JS framework(Jquery,ExtJS,DOJO,Prototype...) because it would simplify your task

Answer (score 0):

Hooray! It's loop closures again! See [422784](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422784/how-to-fix-closure-problem-in-actionscript-3-as3), [643542](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables), [1552941](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/variables-in-anonymous-functions-can-someone-explain-the-following) et al for some more discussion.

> is there a way of performing the same bind without having to create anonymous functions each time?

Yes, in ECMAScript Fifth Edition you get `function.bind`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    document.getElementById('element'+i).onclick= existingFunction.bind(window, i);
```

In the meantime since browsers don't yet generally support it you can monkey-patch an alternative implementation of `bind` (see [the bottom of this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558065/access-event-object-in-event-handler#1558289) for one such) built out of anonymous functions as a fallback.

Alternatively, assign the same event handler function to every element and just have it look at `this.id` to see which element number it is.