# A question about JavaScript's slice and splice methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, splice, arguments

I came across the following code:

```
var f = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);

    // some more code 
};
```

Basically, the result in `args` is an array that is a copy of the `arguments` without its first element.

But what I can't understand exactly is why `f`'s `arguments` (which is an object that holds the function's inputted arguments into an array-like object) object is being passed to the `slice` method and how `slice(1)` is removing the first element (positioned at index 0).

Can anyone please explain it for me?

*P.S.  The code is from this [partial application function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373157/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-function-with-parameters)*

Comment: Array.splice(start, deleteCount) actually removes the element, reindexes the array, and changes its length.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

<Note>
The actual code from that [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321113/how-can-i-pre-set-arguments-in-javascript-function-call-partial-function-applic/321527#321527) is:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

i.e. "slice", not "splice"
</Note>

First of all, the `slice` method is often used to [make a copy of the array it's called on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice):

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = a.slice();  // b is now a copy of a
var c = a.slice(1); // c is now ['b', 'c']
```

So the short answer is that the code is basically emulating:

```
arguments.slice(1); // discard 1st argument, gimme the rest
```

However you can't do that directly. The [special `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) (available inside the execution context of all JavaScript functions), although Array-*like* in that it supports indexing via the `[]` operator with numeric keys, is not actually an Array; You can't `.push` onto it, `.pop` off it, or `.slice` it, etc.

The way the code accomplishes this is by "tricking" the `slice` function (which again is not available on the `arguments` object) to run *in the context of* `arguments`, via [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
Array.prototype.slice // get a reference to the slice method
                      // available on all Arrays, then...
  .call(              // call it, ...
    arguments,        // making "this" point to arguments inside slice, and...
    1                 // pass 1 to slice as the first argument
  )
```

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1)` accomplishes the same thing, but makes an extraneous call to `splice(1)`, which *removes* elements from the array returned from `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` starting at index `1` and continuing to the end of the array. `splice(1)` doesn't work in IE (it's technically missing a 2nd parameter telling it how many items to remove that IE and ECMAScript require).

Comment: Sorry for the code difference, but I copied the code I had pasted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373157/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-function-with-parameters from the answer I linked to in this question, but the author changed the script in the meantime.  Once again, sorry about that

Comment: @Crescent Flesh, I changed the link in my question to point to the original code

Comment: Crescent Fresh, in the Flesh. @Andreas, yes I saw that. I believe my closing paragraph addresses `splice(1)` too, yes?

Comment: Something is bugging me and I have to put it out: `slice()` is supposed to take an argument. It works parameterless in all browsers today that's why I left it in my answer. But technically the last example `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is suppose to be `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)` (i.e. pass 0 as the first argument to the slice function). It essentially defaults to 0 if omitted (again, in all browsers).

Comment: This is the best step by step detailed breakdown of how code works I have in recent memory. Awesome stuff man, thanks.

Comment: +1 great answer. BTW, `special arguments object` link is not working. Maye be it moved to here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 3):

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
```

First takes a copy of `arguments`(*), then removes all but the first item from it (in a non-standard way), and assigns those items being removed to `args`.

The extra array being produced, then altered and thrown away is quite redundant. It would be better to say — as the version in the answer you linked to indeed does:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

Partial function application is also a feature of the `function.bind` method, being standardised by ECMAScript Fifth Edition. Until browsers have implemented it, you can pick up an a fallback JS-native version from the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558065/access-event-object-in-event-handler/1558289#1558289).

*: `array.slice()` is the normal idiom for copying an array, and `array.slice(1)` for taking the tail. It has it be called explicitly through the `Array.prototype` because `arguments` is not an Array, even though it looks just like one, so doesn't have the normal array methods. This is another of JavaScript's weird mistakes.

You quite often see people using the `Array.prototype` methods on objects that aren't Arrays; the ECMAScript Third Edition standard goes out of its way to say this is OK to do for the `arguments` array-like, but **not** that you may also do it on other array-likes that may be host objects, such as NodeList or HTMLCollection. Although you might get away with calling `Array.prototype` methods on a non-Array in many browsers today, the only place it is actually safe to do so is on `arguments`.

Comment: ES5 now explicitly documents many of the Array.prototype methods to work on *any* array-like object, so it should be safe to rely on that continuing to work.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value of a splice is an array of the elements that were removed,
but the original array (or array-like object), is truncated at the splice index.

Making a copy with slice preserves the original arguments array,
presumably for use later in the function.

In this case the same result can be had with `args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)`

```
function handleArguments(){
 var A= [].slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
 //arguments is unchanged
 var s= 'A='+A+'\narguments.length='+arguments.length;

 var B= [].splice.call(arguments, 1);
 // arguments now contains only the first parameter
 s+= '\n\nB='+B+'\narguments.length='+arguments.length;
 return s;
}

// test
alert(handleArguments(1, 2, 3, 4));

returned value:
//var A= [].slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
A=2,3,4
arguments.length=4

//var B= [].splice.call(arguments, 1);
B=2,3,4
arguments.length=1
```