# JavaScript Array splice vs slice

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `splice` and `slice` ?

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array.splice(index, 1);
array.slice(index, 1);
```

Comment: check if this aswer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777705/a-question-about-javascripts-slice-and-splice-methods

Comment: The splice() methods mutate an array by either adding to the array or removing from an array and returns only the removed items.

Comment: They should have interchanged names to communicate their actual meaning e.g. slice piece of cake - cut big cake and give away a portion. But in reality it does exactly opposite by keeping original cake intact and giving a slice of it, how is it possible argh.

Comment: When you have a sandwich, what you really do is have two splices, not two slices. You will have reduced the loaf by doing so. Unintuitive, I know.

Answer (score 427):

`splice()` changes the original array whereas `slice()` doesn't but both of them returns array object.

See the examples below:

```
var array=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.splice(2));
```

This will return `[3,4,5]`. The **original array is affected** resulting in `array` being `[1,2]`.

```
var array=[1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array.slice(2));
```

This will return `[3,4,5]`. The **original array is NOT affected** with resulting in `array` being `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Below is simple fiddle which confirms this:

```js
//splice
var array=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.splice(2));

//slice
var array2=[1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array2.slice(2));


console.log("----after-----");
console.log(array);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: It's also important to observe that the slice() array method can be used to copy arrays by not passing any arguments `arr1 = arr0.slice()`

Comment: You can think of it like `splice` is like a government taking taxes from you. 
Whereas `slice` is more a copy-paste guy.

Comment: `.splice()` is **extremely** unintuitive, I just spent ages trying to figure out why references to the original array were returning `undefined` until I found this thread.

Comment: **splice** or like I tend to say _"**slice** and **p**lunder the values from the caller"_.

Answer (score 126):

Splice and Slice both are Javascript Array functions.

**Splice vs Slice**

1. The splice() method returns the removed item(s) in an array and slice() method returns the selected element(s) in an array, as a new array object.
2. The splice() method changes the original array and slice() method doesn’t change the original array.
3. The splice() method can take n number of arguments and slice() method takes 2 arguments.

**Splice with Example**

Argument 1: Index, Required. An integer that specifies at what position to add /remove items, Use negative values to specify the position from the end of the array.

Argument 2: Optional. The number of items to be removed. If set to 0(zero), no items will be removed. And if not passed, all item(s) from provided index will be removed.

Argument 3…n: Optional. The new item(s) to be added to the array.

```js
var array=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.splice(2));
// shows [3, 4, 5], returned removed item(s) as a new array object.
 
console.log(array);
// shows [1, 2], original array altered.
 
var array2=[6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(array2.splice(2,1));
// shows [8]
 
console.log(array2.splice(2,0));
//shows [] , as no item(s) removed.
 
console.log(array2);
// shows [6,7,9,0]
```

**Slice with Example**

Argument 1: Required. An integer that specifies where to start the selection (The first element has an index of 0). Use negative numbers to select from the end of an array.

Argument 2: Optional. An integer that specifies where to end the selection but does not include. If omitted, all elements from the start position and to the end of the array will be selected. Use negative numbers to select from the end of an array.

```js
var array=[1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array.slice(2));
// shows [3, 4, 5], returned selected element(s).
 
console.log(array.slice(-2));
// shows [4, 5], returned selected element(s).
console.log(array);
// shows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], original array remains intact.
 
var array2=[6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(array2.slice(2,4));
// shows [8, 9]
 
console.log(array2.slice(-2,4));
// shows [9]
 
console.log(array2.slice(-3,-1));
// shows [8, 9]
 
console.log(array2);
// shows [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Though both functions perform quite different tasks, unlike  `splice(x,y)`, in `slice(x,y)` the second argument `y` is not counted from the position of x, but from the first element of the array.

Comment: One more thing I noted : instead of `array.slice(index, count)`, if you use `array.slice((index, count))`, you will get the remaining part after 'slicing'. Try it!

Comment: Edit queue is full, so:

Splice and Slice both are Javascript Array METHODS. They don't exist on their own, they're both Array.prototype methods.

Answer (score 73):

**S LICE**   = Gives part of array & **NO** splitting original array

**SP LICE**  = Gives part of array & **SP**litting original array

I personally found this easier to remember, as these 2 terms always confused me as beginner to web development.

Comment: Splice -> ctrl+X + ctrl+V
Slice -> ctrl +C

Comment: It was awesome, I'll never forget that.

Answer (score 43):

Here is a simple trick to remember the difference between **`slice`** vs **`splice`**

```
var a=['j','u','r','g','e','n'];

// array.slice(startIndex, endIndex)
a.slice(2,3);
// => ["r"]

//array.splice(startIndex, deleteCount)
a.splice(2,3);
// => ["r","g","e"]
```

**`Trick to remember:`**

Think of **`"spl" (first 3 letters of splice)`** as short for "specifiy length", that the second argument should be a length not an index

Comment: It's more than just how you specify arguments. One of them (splice) modifies the base array and the other one does not.

Comment: also could think of splice as split (generates 2 arrays) + slice

Answer (score 27):

The [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method returns a copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.

```
$scope.participantForms.slice(index, 1);
```

This does **NOT** change the `participantForms` array but returns a new array containing the single element found at the `index` position in the original array.

The [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```
$scope.participantForms.splice(index, 1);
```

This will remove one element from the `participantForms` array at the `index` position.

These are the Javascript native functions, AngularJS has nothing to do with them.

Comment: Can anyone give helpful examples and what would be ideal for each? Like situations that you prefer to use splice or slice?

Comment: this answer is partially incorrect. for `splice` the 2nd arg is count of elements in return array , but for `slice` the 2nd arg is the index of the final element to return + 1.  `slice(index,1)` doesn't necessarily return an array of one element starting at `index`. `[1,2,3,4,5].slice(0,1)` returns `[1]` but `[1,2,3,4,5].slice(3,1)` returns `[]` because `1` is interpreted as `final index +1` so `final index = 0` but this is before `start index = 3` so empty array is returned.

Comment: Why is this not the top answer?

Answer (score 18):

#### Splice - [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - [ECMA-262 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.splice)

**Syntax**
`array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`

**Parameters**

- `start`: required. Initial index.
  If `start` is negative it is treated as `"Math.max((array.length + start), 0)"` as per spec (example provided below) effectively from the end of `array`.
- `deleteCount`: optional. Number of elements to be removed (all from `start` if not provided).
- `item1, item2, ...`: optional. Elements to be added to the array from `start` index.

**Returns**: An array with deleted elements (empty array if none removed)

**Mutate original array**: Yes

#### Examples:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Remove first element
console.log('Elements deleted:', array.splice(0, 1), 'mutated array:', array);
// Elements deleted: [ 1 ] mutated array: [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

// array = [ 2, 3, 4, 5]
// Remove last element (start -> array.length+start = 3)
console.log('Elements deleted:', array.splice(-1, 1), 'mutated array:', array);
// Elements deleted: [ 5 ] mutated array: [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

More examples in [MDN Splice examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Examples)

---

#### Slice - [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - [ECMA-262 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.slice)

**Syntax**
`array.slice([begin[, end]])`
**Parameters**

- `begin`: optional. Initial index (default 0).
  If `begin` is negative it is treated as `"Math.max((array.length + begin), 0)"` as per spec (example provided below) effectively from the end of `array`.
- `end`: optional. Last index for extraction but not including (default array.length). If `end` is negative it is treated as `"Math.max((array.length + begin),0)"` as per spec (example provided below) effectively from the end of `array`.

**Returns**: An array containing the extracted elements.

**Mutate original**: No

#### Examples:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Extract first element
console.log('Elements extracted:', array.slice(0, 1), 'array:', array);
// Elements extracted: [ 1 ] array: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

// Extract last element (start -> array.length+start = 4)
console.log('Elements extracted:', array.slice(-1), 'array:', array);
// Elements extracted: [ 5 ] array: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

More examples in [MDN Slice examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Examples)

#### Performance comparison

Don't take this as absolute truth as depending on each scenario one might be performant than the other.
[Performance test](https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-slice-perf)

Answer (score 18):

The `splice()` method returns the removed items in an array. 
The `slice()` method returns the selected element(s) in an array, as a new array object.

The `splice()` method changes the original array and `slice()` method doesn’t change the original array.

- `Splice()` method can take n number of arguments:

  *Argument 1:* Index, Required.

  *Argument 2:* Optional. The number of items to be removed. If set to 0(zero), no items will be removed. And if not passed, all item(s) from provided index will be removed.

  *Argument 3..n:* Optional. The new item(s) to be added to the array.
- `slice()` method can take 2 arguments:

  *Argument 1:* Required. An integer that specifies where to start the selection (The first element has an index of 0). Use negative numbers to select from the end of an array.

  *Argument 2:* Optional. An integer that specifies where to end the selection. If omitted, all elements from the start position and to the end of the array will be selected. Use negative numbers to select from the end of an array.

Comment: per docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice  slice doesnt require arguments

Answer (score 13):

Splice and Slice are built-in Javascript commands -- not specifically AngularJS commands. Slice returns array elements from the "start" up until just before the "end" specifiers. Splice mutates the actual array, and starts at the "start" and keeps the number of elements specified. Google has plenty of info on this, just search.

Comment: Splice _deletes_ the specified number and then inserts any subsequent arguments.

Comment: splice deletes a given number of elements from a given start index e.g. splice(4,1); deletes one element starting from index 4 whereas splice(4,3); deletes three elements starting with the element at index 4. Then after deleting them it returns the deleted values.

Answer (score 9):

Most answers are too wordy.

> - `splice` and `slice` return rest of elements in the array.
> - `splice` mutates the array being operated with elements removed while    `slice` not.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Both return same answer but:

- **SP**lice will mutate your original array.
- **S**lice won't mutate your original array.

Comment: they don't actually return the same thing! `[0,1,2,3].splice(1,1)`modifies the array, removing `1` item (second arg) starting from index `1` (1st arg) and returns the elements removed (which are `[1]` in this case), while `[0,1,2,3].slice(1,1)` makes a copy of the array, starting at index `1` (1st arg) and stops at index `1` (2nd arg), and return that, which in this case is an empty array `[]`. **So they don't both return the same thing.**

Comment: @mockingjay, because `splice` is mutating. its return thing obviously is not the same as `slice`.

Answer (score 7):

The *slice( )* method **copies** a given part of an array and returns that copied part as a new array. It *doesn’t change* the original array.

The *splice( )* method **changes** an array, by adding or removing elements from it.

Here is the **slice** syntax:

```js
array.slice(from, until);

// example
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let newArray = array.slice(1, 3)
console.log({array, newArray})

// output: array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], newArray: [2, 3]
```

*Note*: the Slice( ) method can also be used for strings.

And here is the **splice** syntax:

```js
//For removing elements, we need to give the index parameter,
// and the number of elements to be removed

array.splice(index, number of elements to be removed);


//example
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let newArray = array.splice(1, 3)
console.log({array, newArray})

// output: array: [1, 5, 6], newArray: [2, 3, 4]
```

*Note*: If we don’t define the second parameter, every element starting from the given index will be removed from the array

```js
// For adding elements, we need to give them as the 3rd, 4th, ... parameter
array.splice(index, number of elements to be removed, element, element);

//example
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let newArray = array.splice(1, 3, 'a', 'b')
console.log({array, newArray})

// output: array: [1, ,'a', 'b', 5, 6], newArray: [2, 3, 4]
```

Related links:

[Let’s clear up the confusion around the slice( ), splice( ), & split( ) methods in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lets-clear-up-the-confusion-around-the-slice-splice-split-methods-in-javascript-8ba3266c29ae/)

[Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 6):

## splice & delete Array item by index

> index = 2

```js
//splice & will modify the origin array
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
//slice & won't modify the origin array
const arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

console.log("----before-----");
console.log(arr1.splice(2, 1));
console.log(arr2.slice(2, 1));

console.log("----after-----");
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

```js
let log = console.log;

//splice & will modify the origin array
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

//slice & won't modify the origin array
const arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

log("----before-----");
log(arr1.splice(2, 1));
log(arr2.slice(2, 1));

log("----after-----");
log(arr1);
log(arr2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

slice does not change original array it return new array but splice changes the original array.

```
example: var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
         arr.slice(1,3); // output [2,3] and original array remain same.
         arr.splice(1,3); // output [2,3,4] and original array changed to [1,5,6,7,8].
```

splice method second argument is different from slice method. second argument in splice represent count of elements to remove and in slice it represent end index.

```
arr.splice(-3,-1); // output [] second argument value should be greater then 
0.
arr.splice(-3,-1); // output [6,7] index in minus represent start from last.
```

-1 represent last element so it start from -3 to -1.
Above are major difference between splice and slice method.

Answer (score 4):

Another example:

```
[2,4,8].splice(1, 2) -> returns [4, 8], original array is [2]

[2,4,8].slice(1, 2) -> returns 4, original array is [2,4,8]
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
//splice
var array=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.splice(2));

//slice
var array2=[1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array2.slice(2));


console.log("----after-----");
console.log(array);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Kindly provide more information on what is going on

Answer (score 3):

`slice` and `splice` are intimately connected, but yet serves very different purposes:

The `slice` function is used to select a portion of an array. **Its purpose is its return value**. Its execution does not affect its subject.

The `splice` function is used to remove elements from an array. **Its purpose is to modify its subject**. It still returns a copy of the removed items, for reference, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Slice() and Splice() javascript build-in functions is,
Slice returns removed item but did not change the original array ;
like,

```
        // (original Array)
        let array=[1,2,3,4,5] 
        let index= array.indexOf(4)
         // index=3
        let result=array.slice(index)
        // result=4  
        // after slicing=>  array =[1,2,3,4,5]  (same as original array)
```

but in splice() case it affects original array; like,

```
         // (original Array)
        let array=[1,2,3,4,5] 
        let index= array.indexOf(4)
         // index=3
        let result=array.splice(index)
        // result=[4,5]  
        // after splicing array =[1,2,3]  (splicing affects original array)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 differences:

1. Splice will remove the selected elements from the original array and return them as a new array -Notice that the original will no longer have them-. Slice will create a new array with the selected elements without affecting the original one.
2. Splice receives as parameters the start index and how many elements to remove from that point. Slice receives 2 indexes, start and end.
3. Splice can be used to add elements at a specific position in the array by passing optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

These two methods are very confusing for beginners. I have researched and found 4 key points in `slice` and `splice`. You can read more in detail about [slice vs splice](https://latestjavascript.com/slice-vs-splice-in-javascript-end-your-confusion-today/).

**Slice in JavaScript**

- Slice just returns a specified number of elements from an array. For example you have an array of 10 elements and you want to just get 3 elements from 2nd index.
- It doesn't modify the original array but returns the number of elements.
- The syntax of the slice is `array.slice(startingIndex, elementCount)`

**Splice in JavaScript**

- Splice can also return the selected elements from the array same as the slice but it modifies the original array.
- You can add a new element in an array using splice on a specific index
- You can remove specified elements as well as add new elements at the same time.
- The syntax of using `splice` is `array.splice(startingIndex, removeCounter, newElement(s)[optional])`

**Summary**

The purpose of the slice is to get only selected elements from array and it doesn't modify the original array.
The splice should be used when you want to modify the original array by removing elements and adding new elements.