# Extracting last n elements from array without disturbing original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to extract last n elements from array without splice

I have array like below , I want to get last 2 or n elements from any array in new array [33, 44]

```
[22, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44]
```

I have tried to copy old array to new array and then do splice.But i believe there must be some other better way.

```
var arr = [22, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44] ;
var temp = [];
temp = arr;
temp.splice(-2);
```

Above code is also removing last 2 elements from original array `arr`;

So how can i just extract last n elements from original array without disturning it into new variable

Comment: You can use `slice()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601282/javascript-array-splice-vs-slice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `slice()` instead of `splice()`:

As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```js
var arr = [22, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44] ;

var newArr = arr.slice(-2);

console.log(newArr);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), which does not alter the original array.

```js
var array = [22, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44];
    temp = array.slice(-2);

console.log(temp);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shallow copy with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and then splice it.

Or just use `Array.prototype.slice` as suggested by some other answers.

```js
const a = [22, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44];
console.log(Array.from(a).splice(-2));
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.slice:

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3]
arr.slice(-2); // = [2,3]
arr; // = [0,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [22, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44] ;
var temp = [];
var arrCount = arr.length;
temp.push(arr[arrCount-1]);
temp.push(arr[arrCount-2]);
```