# Does splicing of an array reduce the value of array.length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(l[i]) === 'string') {
      l.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return l;
}
console.log(filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b']));
```

When element 2 (index starts with 0) is spliced why doesn't the length of the array in the for loop change to 3? The last element should not be processed but it is processed.

Comment: Consider using `.filter` instead. `filter_list = arr => arr.filter(a => typeof a !== 'string')`

Comment: Please refer [Array.slice vs Array.splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601282/javascript-array-splice-vs-slice). Also note, looping on array and mutating it at the same time will cause issues.

Comment: If you add `console.log(l.length)` after the splice, you will see it outputs `3`. The last item was not processed. In fact, it was not removed. If it had, you would get `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does splicing of an array reduce the value of array.length?

Yes, because `splice` method modifies the array *inplace*

The solution could be using a `while` *loop*.

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  i = l.length;
  while (i--) {
      if (typeof(l[i]) === 'string') {
          l.splice(i, 1);
      }
  }
  return l;
}

console.log(filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b']));
```

Comment: Or a `for` loop which just goes in reverse order? `for (var i = l.length; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, good point.

Comment: `const result = l.filter(n => typeof n !== 'string')`