# Could I use splice() method without create it to new array?

Tags: javascript

Every time I used `splice()` method to add new objects to array it will become like this:

```
[[{"id": 2, "text": "zebra"}]]
```

and if I use `pop()` method I can't choose an object I want by index. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

`splice()` changes the original array whereas `slice()` doesn't but both of them returns array object.

Refer this : [JavaScript Array splice vs slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601282/javascript-array-splice-vs-slice)