# Remove specified item from array angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I know i can remove last item from array and first but I need to remove specified item based value
Here is my array

```
  arrayItems: {
    volume: number;
    title: string;
  }[];


this.arrayItems = [{
  volume: 11,
  title: 'Title'
}];
```

Here is my example i have html

```
   <div *ngFor="let arrayItem of arrayItems; let i=index">
      <label>{{arrayItem.i}}</label>
      <div (click)="removeItem(i)">remove item</div>
   </div>
```

And to add and remove item

```
  addItem() {
    const item = {
      volume: 2,
      title: 'Naslov 2'
    };
    this.arrayItems.push(item);
  }


  removeItem(index) {
    this.arrayItems.slice(index, 1);
  }
```

But to removeItem() does not work, any idea why this is wrong?

Comment: Use `splice` and not `slice`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use `Array.slice`, use `Array.splice` instead. SLice doesn't change the original array but returns a new one, splice however also modifies the original array (for reference, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601282/javascript-array-splice-vs-slice))

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice` to remove specified item from the JSON array like below:

```
removeItem(index) {
    this.arrayItems.splice(index, 1);
}
```