# In JS, does the result of const newArray = oldArray.splice(0) include elements added during execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, slice, splice

In my JavaScript code, I have a line of code that looks like this:

`const newArray = oldArray.splice(0);`

My question is what happens when there are concurrent modifications to `oldArray` during the execution of this line. Specifically:

1. If new elements are pushed into `oldArray` while splice(0) is executing, will those new elements be included in the `newArray`?
2. After the line is executed, will `oldArray` be emptied, or will it still contain the elements that were added during the execution of splice(0)?

And compare to the following way:

```
const newArray = oldArray.slice();
oldArray = oldArray.slice(newArray.length);
```

Which way is better?

My goal is if the new element added to the `oldArray`, I want to keep them in the `oldArray`, I don't want to loss any data.

I want to make sure I understand the behaviour correctly and handle potential concurrency issues. Thank you for your help!

I don't know how to verify my thought.

Comment: "_concurrent modifications_" are not possible in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since javascript is single-threaded, it is very unlikely that there will be 2 operations on the array at the same time.
So I don't see any difference between the two approaches you mentioned. Nevertheless, the variant with

```
const newArray = oldArray.slice();
oldArray = oldArray.slice(newArray.length);
```

sounds better to me, since you determine the behavior yourself.

For more information about the differences between splice and slice have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601282/javascript-array-splice-vs-slice) ;)