# Calling a class prototype method by a setInterval event

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript class.

One method of this class sets up a timer using setInterval function. The method that I want to call every time the event fires is defined inside the same class.

The question is, how can I pass this method as a parameter to the setInterval function?

One attempt was setInterval('this.showLoading(), 100). But doesn't work. This method access class properties, so I need the 'this' reference.

This is the sample code:

```
    function LoadingPicture(Id)
    {
        this.imgArray = null;
        this.currentImg = 0;
        this.elementId = Id;
        this.loadingTimer = null;
    }


   LoadingPicture.prototype.showLoading = function()
    {
        if(this.currentImg == imgArray.length)
            currentImg = 0;

        document.getElementById(this.elementId).src = imgArray[this.currentImg++].src;
    }


    LoadingPicture.prototype.StartLoading = function()
    {
        document.getElementById(this.elementId).style.visibility = "visible";
        loadingTimer = setInterval("showLoading()", 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

setInterval can take a function directly, not just a string. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

i.e.

```
loadingTimer = setInterval(showLoading, 100);
```

But, for optimal browser compatibility, you should use a closure with an explicit reference:

```
 var t = this;
 loadingTimer = setInterval(function(){t.showLoading();}, 100);
```

Comment: The latter approach being the more generally applicable. +1

Comment: Yeah, depends... I think the former works in AS3, but I can't remember if it does cross-browser in JS. The latter is usually the safest.

Comment: I tend to call the variable `that`. As in: var that = this; :)

Answer (score 27):

```
loadingTimer = setInterval("this.showLoading()", 100);
```

Firstly, don't use string arguments to setInterval/Timeout. It's dodgy in the same way as using `eval`, and may similarly fail with CSP security restrictions in the future. So instead:

```
loadingTimer = setInterval(this.showLoading, 100);
```

However, as you say, this will lose the owner reference so the called function won't see the right `this`. In the future (the newly-defined ECMAScript Fifth Edition), you will be able to bind the function to its owner with `function.bind`:

```
loadingTimer = setInterval(this.showLoading.bind(this), 100);
```

and if you implement `function.bind` yourself for browsers that don't yet have it (see the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558065/#1558289)), you can use this syntax today.

Otherwise, you will need to use an explicit closure, as in the example Computer Linguist just posted.

Answer (score 6):

All the answers above are acceptable. I just wanted to add that the binding of `this` can also be solved by using an arrow function. For example, these are all equivalent to each other. However, the lexical scope is maintained when using arrow functions:

```js
 // Arrow function - my preferred method
 loadingTimer = setInterval(() => this.showLoading(), 100);

 // .bind method
 loadingTimer = setInterval(this.showLoading.bind(this), 100);

 // Other method
 var t = this;
 loadingTimer = setInterval(function(){t.showLoading();}, 100);
```

Hope this helps :D